# How to include a regex into an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm witing a function that returns a HTML `class` according to the last part of the url:

```
const currentPage = this.$route.path
const pinkPages = [ '/', '/forgot-pass', '/reset-pass' ]
if (pinkPages.indexOf(currentPage) > -1) return 'footer-pink'
```

It work fine, the problem is that `/reset-pass` actually has more characters at the end. For example, `/reset-pass/123`.

How can I make it so that the function returns `footer-pink` when the URL is `/reset-pass/1234` or `/reset-pass/abcd` or other pattern like that?

Comment: can you explain "How can I include that to the pinkPages array, so 'footer-pink` is returned when the URL matches that?" more?

Comment: @KhalidHabib I edited the question.

Comment: instead of adding regex in array, you can create dynamic regex using `new RegExp()`.

Comment: @alex, can you show me the current `currentPage` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a regex to try to match with current page ?

```
console.log(matchWith('/forgot-pass'));
console.log(matchWith('/reset-pass/'));
console.log(matchWith('/reset-pass/toto'));
console.log(matchWith('/another'));

function matchWith(page) {
  var regex = /(^\/$|\/forgot-pass$|\/reset-pass\/(.*))/
    if(page.match(regex))
      return true
    return false
}
// for your sample
if(matchWith(this.$route.path)) {
   return 'footer-pink';
}
```

Look this plunker, maybe it's your answer : https://plnkr.co/edit/sC5VCadDLlRJwH6rpB1T?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. That was a very simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can store regex in string format and then create an array of regex.

```js
var arr = ["test", "foo", "test2", "bar", "test3"];
var reg_str = ["^test", "o$"];
var regex_list = reg_str.map(function(r) {
  return new RegExp(r);
})

var filtered_list = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return regex_list.filter(function(r) {
    return r.test(item);
  }).length > 0;
});

console.log(filtered_list);
```